# Docker - Unable to start Webpack Dev Server on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I am trying to start Webpack Dev Server in a Rails app on a Digital Ocean Kubernetes Cluster. I can't figure out the correct command. The app works in Docker locally.

I keep getting errors like this:

> Error: failed to start container "exactpos-webpack": Error response from
>   daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"bin/bash\": stat bin/bash: no such
>   file or directory": unknown Back-off restarting failed container

Here is the code from my docker-compose.yml file:

```
webpack_dev_server: build: .
command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server 
ports:
- 3035:3035 
volumes:
- .:/usr/src/app
- gem_cache:/gems 
env_file:
- .env/development/web
- .env/development/database environment:
- WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Here is my kubectl deployment yaml file:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: exactpos-webpack
spec:
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 150
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1  
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: exactpos-webpack
      tier: webpack
  template:
    metadata:
      name: exactpos-webppack
      labels:
        app: exactpos-webpack
        tier: webpack
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerhub-cred
      containers:             
        - name: exactpos-webpack
          image: index.docker.io/markhorrocks/exactpos_webpacker_dev_server:prod
          command: ["bin/bash","-c", "./bin/webpack_dev_server"]
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3500       
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 3500
            initialDelaySeconds: 150
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 10
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 3500
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 10
          env:
          - name: RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT
            value: "true"
          - name: RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES
            value: "true"
          - name: DATABASE_NAME
            value: "exactpos_production"
          - name: DATABASE_PORT
            value: "5432"
          - name: DATABASE_URL
            value: "postgres"
          - name: DATABASE_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: "db-user"
                key: "username"
          - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: "db-user-pass"
                key: "password"
          - name: REDIS_URL
            value: "redis"
          - name: REDIS_PORT
            value: "6379"
          - name: RAILS_ENV
            value: "production"
          - name: WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST
            value: "0.0.0.0"
          - name: SECRET_KEY_BASE
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: "secret-key-base"
                key: "secret-key-base"
```

Comment: A good first debugging step would be to make your local and Kubernetes configurations match closer.  That means not hiding the image content with a bind mount in your `docker-compose.yml`, and not wrapping the launch script in a `bash -c` invocation in the Kubernetes pod spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deployment.yaml has following :

```
command: ["bin/bash","-c", "./bin/webpack_dev_server"]
```

There is no `bin/bash` present in docker image. It should be like:

```
command: ["/bin/bash","-c", "./bin/webpack_dev_server"]
```

I believe, it will resolve your problem.

EDIT1: I again looked at your docker-compose.yml file and see the following line:

```
volumes:
- .:/usr/src/app
```

It means at run time of docker you copied all the files from `.` directory to `/usr/src/app`. Is the `config/webpacker.yml` was present at that location? OR you overlayed `/usr/src/app` from whatever it was in `.` directory at the run time. Could you please share DockerFile of your app as well to better understanding?

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that as well. Now I get 'webpack dev_server configuration not found in /usr/src/app/config/webpacker.yml[production].
Please run bundle exec rails webpacker:install to install Webpacker'

Comment: Okay, Does your docker container have that file `/usr/src/app/config/webpacker.yml`. You can also check if the script you're running while creating of k8s pod, you're able to run on standalone docker image.

Comment: I don't know how to check the file but the file exists in the dev app and so it would be built into the image. I don't know how to run the rails install as a single kubectl command

Comment: Turns out I don't need webpacker in production anyway. Precompile assets failed on no db pwd in the environment.